# Enable Windows Event Log by Managed Code (.NET) / Command Line

Tags: c#, .net, event-log

Is there a programmatic way which allows me to enable an [EventLog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/34xfdz6a) if it was disabled by default?
In short, I just need to know if I can enable a specific EventLog so that I can use the events programmatically.

Thanks

Comment: This question assumes that it is possible to disable an event log.  You ought to document that first.

Comment: Well, you can enable and disable event log manually. I was wondering if you can enable/disable logging programatically but I am interested in enabling and not disable.

Comment: @Saher You can't disable individual logs in Windows Server 2008 R2/Windows 7 and I believe Windows Server 2008/Vista. You can stop Event Log service (and start it to enable log). I think that it is possible to disable individual logs in Windows Server 2003 but I'm not sure. I think it's possible to enable custom logs though. (As in not the system ones)

Comment: Hey @LukeP : can you document that please? Do you know of any resource that can give more info about this? Thanks

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you're trying to achieve? What is the target OS is it a system log or a custom one?

Comment: Something like this log maybe :Microsoft-Windows-GroupPolicy/Operational

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To Enable the Windows Event Log use the [wevtutil](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732848%28v=WS.10%29.aspx)

In particular to enable the Word pad log do the following:

```
wevtutil sl "Microsoft-Windows-Wordpad/Admin" /e:true
```

Comment: Writing this comment to add some search keywords for those who wanted "enable event log by name in command line" but getting "how to enable Windows Event Log Service" instead

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're talking about enabling/disabling system logs (Application, Security, Setup, System) I don't think it's possible.

Here's Event Log on Windows Dev center (required deeper poking to find useful info)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa964766%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Here's part about registry settings:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363648%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Group Policy setting:
http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2008/08/12/event-logging-policy-settings-in-windows-server-2008-and-vista.aspx

Which interestingly allow you to enable or disable Setup log but none of the other default ones.

I just think that if you can't do it through registry or group policy then it can't be done.

**Edit:**

There is no way to programatically enable/disable event logs through the API. The only proof I have is that it's not there. So I checked other ways: PowerShell, WMI, Registry, Group Policy - something you can control from within the code. No joy. However, the only way to disable event log is to stop the service.

Comment: I see, but are you talking of progrmmatically enable/disable? I thought these articles are using the UI to configure

Comment: Hey @LukeP: How about activating other Logs (non-System logs) like: Microsoft-Windows-GroupPolicy/Operational

Answer (score 1):

This should enable the event log programatically. It uses an EventLogSession parameter

```
    var elSession = new EventLogSession("computername", "domain", "username", password, SessionAuthentication.Default);
    var elConfig = new EventLogConfiguration("Microsoft-Windows-Wordpad/Admin", elSession);
    if (!elConfig.IsEnabled)
    {
        elConfig.IsEnabled = true;
        elConfig.SaveChanges();
    }
```